Can't solve Socket.io error in MERN app. Proxy error: Could not proxy request socket.io
I've been trying to run an old e-commerce app to make a list of functionalities. No matter what I do, I can't solve this socket.io error.
Proxy error: Could not proxy request
/socket.io/EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P5yQHS1&sid=bIqFyYIUht7r8-l9AAAC from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.

It appears when I update the server.js file. Moreover, when I restart the server I get the following errors in the Chrome console.
Chrome console log
My proxy in frontend is set to http://localhost:5000/
My backend package.json scripts look like this:
scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "server-prod": "node server.js",
    "server-dev": "npx nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix ../frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server-dev\" \"npm run client\"",
    "seed:data": "node seeder/seeder",
    "seed:data-d": "node seeder/seeder -d"
  },

I am running Xubuntu 22.04 LTS.
What I've tried so far:

Add/Remove the '/' from the end.

Change the localhost with 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.0.

Adding --ignore client in start script.

Changing my IP address with localhost


